# Error when declaring UITableView object

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin.iOS 6.3 and I'm having a weird problem: when I declare (not even initialize) a UITableView object, I receive an error:

> Type is not derived from System.Attribute. Parameter name: attirbute
>   type.

Weird thing is it only happens when I try to run the app on the device (iPod touch 4Gen, iOS 6.1.3). On the simulator everything is just fine.

Here's the code that triggers this error:

```
public partial class ActorsListView : UIViewController
{
    public ActorsListView () : base ("ActorsListView", null)
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
    }

    private UITableView table;

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        table = new UITableView(View.Bounds); // defaults to Plain style
        string[] tableItems = new string[] {"Vegetables","Fruits","Flower Buds","Legumes","Bulbs","Tubers"};
        table.Source = new TableSource(tableItems);
        Add (table);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked to Xamarin support about this, this a problem with a beta version of the framework.
To fix this I had to clean solution and re-build it. Then everything worked on the device.